# Using a HSQLDB in in-memory mode for testing with maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, hsqldb

**The Situation:**

Currently we use a HSQLDB in server mode for integration testing. We are using a self-made maven plugin which initialized the Database to our testing needs (creating schemas, migrate with flyway scripts etc..).

Now to speed up the integration tests i'd like to use HSQL in in-memory mode instead.

**The Problem:**

When i change the connection urls so that they use the HSQLDB in in-memory mode the initialization runs fine as well as the connection from the integration tests. But the data and the schemas that has been initialized is not available in the integration tests.

The reason is that when the maven plugin is done initializing the database it seems like the jvm used for that is shut down and the connection from the integration test creates **a vanilla empty HSQLDB** in-memory.

**The Question:**

Is there a way to tell a maven plugin to run in the same JVM or process or whatever is needed so that the plugin and the integration tests will share the same memory and therefor use the same hsqldb ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can force the tests to run in the same JVM process as Maven and its plugins. The appropriate setting is called `forkCount`, see the respective docs for [Surefire](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#forkCount) and [Failsafe](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#forkCount) docs.

Note: The examples below use current (2021) versions of the plugins, but the `forkCount` parameter was already introduced in version 2.14 in 2013.

#### Surefire

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>0</forkCount>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

#### Failsafe

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>0</forkCount>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```